# Javascript dialog box won't open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid, modal-dialog

I've got a jqGrid that when a user edits a row, they need to click a button to apply the changes.  This button should create a dialog box, which should trigger an ajax call with the option selected.

However, the dialog box never opens.  Firebug will stop at breakpoints within the function that creates it, but never does what it's supposed to.

```
function confirm_dialog(rowData){
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal:true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function(){
                ajax_call(rowData, "yes");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "No": function(){
                ajax_call(rowData, "no");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}

function ajax_call(rowData, option){
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{django_base}}',
        data: {'data':rowData, 'option':option},
        type: 'POST',
        error: function(){
            window.alert("There was an error!");
        },
        success: function(){
            window.alert("Changes made successfully!");
        }
    });
}

$(function(){
    //...
    baseGrid = new BaseGrid("#the-jqGrid", opts);
    //...setting grid format
    baseGrid.addButton("edit",
        { caption:'Confirm Changes', onClickButton:confirm_dialog() });
}
```

I've placed a breakpoint at the beginning of confirm_dialog and ajax_call.  It will hit the confirm_dialog break during page load, but not when the button is clicked.  The break in ajax_call is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

If is this your production code, then you missed a comma:

```
function ajax_call(rowData, option){
$.ajax({
    url: '{{django_base}}',
    data: {'data':rowData, 'option':option},
    type: 'POST',
    error: function(){
        window.alert("There was an error!");
    }, **<-------missed comma**
    success: function(){
        window.alert("Changes made successfully!");
    }
});
}
```

EDIT
I made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/94cfma4m/ I think everything is OK with the code itself, maybe the rowData source is invalid?